# Calculus question about Intermediate Value Theorem and roots

Tags: calculus

Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root of equation
$$
x^3 + 2x-\frac{1}{x}=0
$$ 
in $(\frac{1}{4},1)$. Find this root to two decimal places.

Comment: What have you tried? Try not to give commands to solve a problem since we are not here to do homework for you.

Comment: Finding the root of an equation, one that closely resembles a quadratic polynomial... in no way makes this a calculus problem.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the advice. I came across this site and wanted to see what kind of response I would get to a simple question as I need some help getting through 1st year calculus.

Comment: Proper tagging will only serve your interests. Since it will attract the people who are knowledgeable in the subject and deter those who are not. You avoid incompetent or misguided answers. (this is not a formal answer, by the way, its a comment for a good reason).  Its a decent site for the most part but people will treat you like you should have already known the answer before you asked the question. Its happened to me plenty so far.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for existence: if you let
$$f(x) := x^3 + 2x - \frac{1}{x},$$
note that $f(\frac{1}{4}) < 0, f(1) > 0$. Hence, ...

Hint for value: to calculate the zero, note that 
$$x^3 + 2x - \frac{1}{x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow y^2 + 2y -1 =0,$$
if you define $y := x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's $f(x)= x^3 + 2x-\frac{1}{x}$. The Intermediate Value Theorem call us: if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(a)<r<f(b)$ then there is $x\in[a,b]$ such that 
$$
f(x)=r
$$
In this case $a=\frac{1}{4}$, $r=0$ and $b=1$. The difficulty is to prove that $f$ is continuous in the interval $[\frac{1}{4},1]$.

If you convince yourself that the function is continuously looking at the [graph of $f$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%20%2b%202x-1/x) then simply apply the theorem and get a root in the interval.

How $h(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=x^3+2x$ are continuous in the interval $[\frac{1}{4},1]$ and sum of continuous functions is a continuous function then f(x)=h(x)+g(x) is continuous on the interval $[\frac{1}{4},1]$.